# How to use powershell to rename batch files?

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I have a lot of files in a folder:
aa001.txt
aa002.txt
...
I want to rename them to:
bb001.txt
bb002.txt
...

Can I use PowerShell to do such renaming?
Thanks!

Comment: You can, its called `Rename-Item` and `ForEach` loops. What part of your code are you getting stuck on? Please show your current efforts so we can troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Drew, I am not stuck on it, I don't know if I could as I haven't learnt how to use powershell, but as you told me it is feasible, I will go into these “Rename-Item" and "ForEach", thanks.

Comment: *Hi Drew, I am not stuck on it, I don't know if I could as I haven't learnt how to use powershell, but as you told me it is feasible, I will go into these “Rename-Item" and "ForEach", thanks* this is a textbook example of what Stack Overflow tries to avoid at questions or as aptly put by the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), "Don't ask about questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: Hi Nico, of course you are correct, but also in my question, I clearly asked "Can I" but not "How". Actually, I searched for this task a while, but I still don't know if it is possible, then I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the community wants to see some effort and or research, but this is a pretty simple task with PowerShell, so I'm going to go ahead and answer.

```
# Establish test files
1..20 |
ForEach-Object{
    New-Item -Path 'c:\temp\06-02-21' -ItemType File -Name ("aa" + $_.ToString("000")+ ".txt")
}

# Demonstrate renames:
Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp\06-02-21' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('aa', 'bb') }
```

The rename only takes place in one line. The previous `ForEach-Object` just establishes test files for me to work with.  The Rename simply pipes the output from `Get-ChildItem` to `Rename-Item`, a delay bind script block is used as the argument to `-NewName` parameter. Granted this will depend on the input names and how you want to alter them, but it shows that you can use the incoming data to determine the new name etc.